# Extend an entity to create a computed observable that requires a navigation property

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm trying to extend an entity to create a computed observable that requires a navigation property:

```
app.domain.indicador = function () {
    this.ValorMetaActual = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            console.log(this.ValoresMeta); //navigation property: undefined
            return 0;
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    }, this);
};
```

The problem is that when the observable is created, the navigation property does not yet exist.

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Is "indicador" an entityType constructor? Have you considered registering an initializer to define the computed? The dependent navigation property will have been defined by the time your initializer is called.

Comment: indicador is an entityType, yes. I'm extending the entity as explained here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities ( Section: Add Knockout computeds ) and registering in the metadataStore ( store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Indicador", app.domain.indicador); ). I have other extended entities that works fine with normal properties. This is the first time that i'm trying to use a navigation property inside a computed observable. In case it is relevant, the variable ValoresMeta is a collection. Tomorrow  i can provide more code ( 09:46pm here :) )

Comment: You found a subtle bug in the Breeze KO model library. We're fixing it. Thanks for finding it. Meanwhile, your logic should work if it is in the initializer. Or at least it works in my emulation of your example. We'll let you know here when we fix the problem for the constructor.

Comment: Well that was easy :)  See Jay's comment below about the fix in v.0.76.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in v 0.76.3.  Please let us know if this fixes your issue. ... And thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the issue is that you have your computed value displayed somewhere on the page - and is coming up as undefined. If you make your navigation property (`this.ValoresMeta`) an observable then Knockout will update the display value of `ValorMetaActual` whenever `ValoresMeta` is finally assigned.

```
app.domain.indicador = function () {
    this.ValoresMeta = ko.observable(0);
    this.ValorMetaActual = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            console.log(this.ValoresMeta());
            return 0;
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    }, this);
};
```

The above code assigns `0` as the default value for ValoresMeta. You may want some other default value, but you should have some default value so that your computation doesn't end up as undefined.